# Am creating a jwt authentication and authorization service for my angular application. But , getting error when implementing the observables

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, jwt

created user class and and required interfaces as follows :

*user.ts*

```
import { Role } from '../auth/auth.enum'

export interface IUser {
  _id: string
  email: string
  name: IName
  picture: string
  role: Role | string
  userStatus: boolean
  dateOfBirth: Date | null | string
  level: number
  address: {
    line1: string
    line2?: string
    city: string
    state: string
    zip: string
  }
  phones: IPhone[]
  readonly fullName?: string
}
export interface IName {
  first: string
  middle?: string
  last: string
}
export enum PhoneType {
  None = 'none',
  Mobile = 'mobile',
  Home = 'home',
  Work = 'work',
}
export interface IPhone {
  type: PhoneType
  digits: string
  id: number
}

export class User implements IUser {
  constructor(
    // tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
    public _id = '',
    public email = '',
    public name = { first: '', middle: '', last: '' } as IName,
    public picture = '',
    public role = Role.None,
    public dateOfBirth: Date | null = null,
    public userStatus = false,
    public level = 0,
    public address = {
      line1: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
      zip: '',
    },
    public phones: IPhone[] = []
  ) {}
  static Build(user: IUser) {
    if (!user) {
      return new User()
    }
    if (typeof user.dateOfBirth === 'string') {
      user.dateOfBirth = new Date(user.dateOfBirth)
    }
    return new User(
      user._id,
      user.email,
      user.name,
      user.picture,
      user.role as Role,
      user.dateOfBirth,
      user.userStatus,
      user.level,
      user.address,
      user.phones
    )
  }
  public get fullName(): string {
    if (!this.name) {
      return ''
    }
    if (this.name.middle) {
      return `${this.name.first} ${this.name.middle} ${this.name.last}`
    }
    return `${this.name.first} ${this.name.last}`
  }
  toJSON(): object {
    const serialized = Object.assign(this)
    delete serialized._id
    delete serialized.fullName
    return serialized
  }
}
```

*auth.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs'

import { IUser, User } from '../user/user'
import { Role } from './auth.enum'

export interface IAuthStatus {
  isAuthenticated: boolean
  userRole: Role
  userId: string
}
export interface IServerAuthResponse {
  accessToken: string
}
export const defaultAuthStatus: IAuthStatus = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  userRole: Role.None,
  userId: '',
}
export interface IAuthService {
  readonly authStatus$: BehaviorSubject<IAuthStatus>
  readonly currentUser$: BehaviorSubject<IUser>
  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<void>
  logout(clearToken?: boolean): void
  getToken(): string
}
@Injectable()
export abstract class AuthService implements IAuthService {
  readonly authStatus$: new BehaviorSubject<IAuthStatus>(defaultAuthStatus)
  readonly currentUser$: new BehaviorSubject<IUser>(new User())
  constructor() {}
  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<void> {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.')
  }
  logout(clearToken?: boolean): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.')
  }
  getToken(): string {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.')
  }
}
```

The following is the inheritance chart of various classes
[inheritance chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awrle.png)

Now am getting various errors on auth.service.ts file when I add authStatus$ and currentUser$ observable properties in AuthService abstract class.

Following is the stackblitz link to project. [project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-ktgusk?file=src/app/auth/auth.service.ts)

says authStatus$ and currentUser$ not assigned in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the declarations of authStatus$ and currentUser$ to:

```
readonly authStatus$: BehaviorSubject<IAuthStatus> = new BehaviorSubject<IAuthStatus>(defaultAuthStatus);
readonly currentUser$: BehaviorSubject<IUser> = new BehaviorSubject<IUser>(new User());
```